# Load page and content (graphs) separately

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django website that contains a page with a lot of big data graphs. To build these graphs a few big queries are made, which causes the page to take a long time to load. As the data keeps growing, I've been trying to optimize the queries, but still it doesn't load very fast.

Now my question is what I could do to make the page load separately from the graphs. So, the website would load, the user would see the navigation bar, and the outline of the graphs. Meanwhile the graphs would be build up using the data from the database.
I've seen this happening on some websites, for example the Office Exchange admin panel, which shows the outline of the graph, while a loading icon is shown and the data will slowely fill said graph.

I've looked into possible solutions but couldn't really find a satisfying answer. I found Celery which can be used to separate code tasks, but I'm not sure whether this is what I'm looking for here, as I basically only have two tasks. The basic website and the graphs after that.

Could someone tell me whether Celery is the actual way to go here, or whether I'm looking for some other solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try use the load graph in a "ajax way" ?

Comment: I'm using the Morris library to make the graphs, which is a ajax library. What the 'ajax way' is, is unknown to me

Comment: Ajax way is a form to load data without lock the page, if you call your html render and then after you call a javascript function to load data coud be a Ajax way. But, if you have a large ammount of data the browser could respond error like "bad gateway". Let me think in something and I back to help you

Comment: I've looked up a few examples and this indeed seems like the solution I was looking for. You already helped me a lot with this info. Thanks.

Comment: I see a lot of examples but they seem all very specific and not really what I'm looking for. 
What I want is an empty graph that gets popluted after the click of a button. The buttonclick should call a views.py function which gets the data using queries and returns that to the Ajax/jQuery function/graph